# Failed to decode downloaded font. OTS parsing error. VueJs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, fonts, font-face

I am trying to import a web-font in a  certain component in my Vue App (created with Vue cli webpack template). Inside the one of my components I try to import the fonts, by referencing a _fonts.scss within the project that has the contents:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SomeFont';
  src: url('~/assets/fonts/SomeFont-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('~/assets/fonts/SomeFont-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then, when I open the app, I get this error:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/assets/fonts/SomeFont-Regular.woff2
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/assets/fonts/SomeFont-Regular.woff
```

With this too:

```
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I searched online for this problem and found nothing, or some relatable circumstances

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use relative path when importing fonts in `url()`. Without `'~/fontPath'`

Example

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url("../assets/fonts/MyFont.woff2") format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: But why does this help?!

Comment: **This is the correct answer** from the hundreds of answers here on SO. Paths are the number one problem when working with fonts. I'm building a VueJS app in VSC and all I did was to change `/src/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?uoqhn7` to `../src/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?uoqhn7` and it worked. I have no idea why. **Vue has some 'issues' with relative paths.** For example: in the same file `img src="@/assets/images/image.png"` will work, but `src: url("@/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?uoqhn7");` will not.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the answer here [Vue Cli 3 Local fonts not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422304/vue-cli-3-local-fonts-not-loading). In short, you have to replace `../assets` with `~@/assets`.