# Vue Cli 3 Local fonts not loading

Tags: vue.js, font-face, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, webpack-file-loader

When trying to load custom local fonts in Vue CLI 3 the fonts still will not appear. I am not receiving any error messages. The inspector shows the correct rule being loaded, but fonts are falling back to `serif` on #app. Fonts are not showing up in my dist folder anywhere.

I have tried adding loaders in vue.config.js, changing url paths, and moving the @font-face rules around to different locations, changing the public path to ' ' and '/', importing scss into main.js.

Font loading:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.otf') format('font-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('font-woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('font-truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And use within App.vue:

```
<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular', serif;
}
</style>
```

That styling is placed within my `main.scss` file. The file structure as follows:

```
src
  assets
    fonts
      OpenSans-Regular.eot
      OpenSans-Regular.woff
      etc
  styles
    main.scss
  App.vue
vue.config.js
```

`vue.config.js` file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  css: {
    sourceMap: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried a chainWebpack in `vue.config.js` to no avail:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .module
      .rule("file")
      .test(/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,)
      .use("url-loader")
      .loader("url-loader")
      .options({
        limit: 10000,
        name: 'assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      })
      .end();
  }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Did you try

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
src: url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
src: url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.otf') format('font-opentype'),
     url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('font-woff'),
     url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('font-truetype'),
     url('~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Works for me Vue CLI 3, no `vue.config.js` settings.

I'm loading my styles like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import router from './router';
import store  from './store';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import styles from './scss/app.scss';

import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Not sure if that is good practice.

Comment: If you have lint, you can just import "./scss/app.scss";

Answer (score 5):

What I ended up doing was moving to a file loader method to get the fonts to package over and set the the public path.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'assets/',
  publicPath: '/', // Base directory for dev
  css: {
    sourceMap: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("fonts")
      .test(/\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/)
      .use("file-loader")
        .loader("file-loader")
        .tap(options => {
          options = {
            // limit: 10000,
            name: '/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          }
          return options
        })
        .end()
  }
};
```

File-loader doesn't see the files unless called in the js so I imported them in `main.js` The console log is to navigate around the linter flagging unused imports

```
// Fonts need to be called in js for webpack to see and copy over
import OpenSansReg from './assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf';
import OpenSansLight from './assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf';
import OpenSansBold from './assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf';


console.log(OpenSansReg, OpenSansBold, OpenSansLight);
```

then in one of my scss files

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I just took out that 'format()' thing and works... Finally..

Answer (score 1):

I stuck my custom icon-font in the head tags of my initial index.html page Which also has a custom font import. The same page that you would stick your `<div id="vue-app"></div>`. All the other pages /components can use the font-family for me.

`<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="icon-font/styles.css" />
</head>`

But if i try any other location in the project it fails. and the Scss doesnt even compile.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me
In src folder main.js just added:

```
import '../src/fonts/fonts.css'
```

in the font the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv4240';
    src: url('~@/fonts/Conv4240/4240.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
      url('~@/fonts/Conv4240/4240.woff') format('woff'),
      url('~@/fonts/Conv4240/4240.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('~@/fonts/Conv4240/4240.otf') format('opentype'),
      url('~@/fonts/Conv4240/4240.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And everything started to work