# How to use base64-inline-loader in Vue CLI project to embed font files in CSS?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, configuration, base64, vue-cli

I am importing some custom font files into scss file for a vuejs project. When build, it creates these font-related files in `/dist` folder, along with `app.js` and `app.css` files. The files include `font-name.ttf`, `font-name.woff`, `font-name.woff2` and `font-name.svg`

I want to embed these font files in `app.css` file as in base64 data uri when project build.

---

There is an npm package named [base64-inline-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-inline-loader) and this seems to be a good choice for my problem.

The documentation of the package indicates a method of using it with webpack config. Since my project is using vue-cli 3 and `vue-cli-service` to run build commands, I know I need to use `vue.config.js` file to properly config **base64-inline-loader**.

I am not a big webpack expert and only knows basic concepts of it. I am having trouble in configuring the package in `vue.config.js` file.
Hope there is somebody who already has some experience of using the same package preferably in Vue.js project.

Please provide me with the `vue.config.js` file that works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen from default Vue CLI [webpack config](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/52ae1c8a9b281183d751c4847b5bf07aa8b65094/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js#L124), `webpack` processes font through `url-loader`:

```
webpackConfig.module
  .rule('fonts')
  .test(/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i)
  .use('url-loader')
  .loader('url-loader')
  .options(genUrlLoaderOptions('fonts'))
```

So first off you need to delete previous loaders applied to that rule, and set up needed(`base64-inline-loader`).

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {

  const fontsRule = config.module.rule('fonts')

  // clear all existing loaders.
  // if you don't do this, the loader below will be appended to
  // existing loaders of the rule.
  fontsRule.uses.clear()

  config.module
    .rule('fonts')
    .test(/\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/)
    .use('base64-inline-loader')
    .loader('base64-inline-loader')
    .tap(options => {
      // modify the options...    
      return options
     })
    .end()
  }
}
```

P.S. Helpful links:

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422304/vue-cli-3-local-fonts-not-loading).

[Replacing Loaders of a Rule](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#replacing-loaders-of-a-rule).

[Adding a New Loader](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader).

Comment: Yes it works Javas, thank you.
Instead of `tap(options => {})` I used `.options({name: "..."})` :)

Answer (score 0):

`base64-inline-loader` is deprecated and archived on GitHub.

In Webpack 4 use the `url-loader`.
See this URL for an example of base64 encoding:

https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/#generator

Example:

```
config.module.rules.delete('fonts');

config.module
  .rule('fonts')
  .test(/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i)
  .use('url-loader')
  .loader('url-loader')
  // Inline everything, adjust or remove the limit if needed
  .options({
    limit: 10000000, // Inline fonts smaller than 10MB
  })
  .end();
```

In Webpack 5 use `asset/inline` loader.
See this URL:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Example:

```
config.module.rules.delete('fonts');

config.module
  .rule('fonts')
  .test(/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i)
  .type('asset/inline')
  .parser({
    dataUrlCondition: {
      maxSize: 1000000, // Inline fonts smaller than 1MB
    },
  });
```