# Base64 of webpack inline font

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to get the font that is in ./src/assets/fonts and convert it to base64

my config-overrides.js

```
    addWebpackModuleRule({
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'ttf-loader',
            options: {
                name: './src/assets/fonts/[hash].[ext]'
            }
        }
    ]
}),
```

and the file itself, in which I import this font, where I already convert it to base64

```
import font from '../assets/fonts/font.ttf'

const someFun = () =>{
    return btoa(font);
}
```

But I am getting error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/ttf-loader/src/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| module.exports = createFontFamily({
>   ttf: export default __webpack_public_path__ + 
"./src/assets/fonts/7233a7aee250f9b77fba5f735143ad39.ttf",
|   woff: export default __webpack_public_path__ + 
"./src/assets/fonts/f46b66ed2d54e5321411edfe916b7300.woff",
|  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use base64-inline-loader in Vue CLI project to embed font files in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339205/how-to-use-base64-inline-loader-in-vue-cli-project-to-embed-font-files-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I changed the loader to this

```
 loader: 'base64-inline-loader'
```

and now everything works. It will automatically convert the file to base64

Comment: base64-inline-loader is deprecated and archived on GitHub.